# Eclipse git Synchronize perspective shows src folder

Tags: java, eclipse, git

In my java project, I have made changes to one java file. Instead of seeing only the package in which the java source file is changed, I am also seeing src/, src/main, src/main/java and all the packages down to that package.

[image]

Thanks for ur help

Comment: please add a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

in synchronize mode click on show git commits button.
In that menu select java workspace.
then you will get only file structure you modified.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to change the package presentation mode to 'hierarchical', there's a kind of inverted triangle like 'v' in the upper right corner of the project explorer (if you're seeing changes in it).

[image: menu package presentation mode]

Also, if you're in the synchronize perspective, you could change the show filter like @venkateshthigala said

[image]